# K-9 Email App Not Finding All Folders - Labels/Folders

Tags: email, k9-mail

Quick question, I have a problem in that my K-9 mail application is not finding any of my Google Mail IMAP folders/labels.  Now I can send and receive messages without problem, however I'm curious as to why K-9 cannot find any of my folders such as [Google Mail]/-Poeticemails

Any ideas?  Am I getting confused between labels/folder and the two aren't interchangable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you enabled the visibility of these labels/folders from the IMAP section of options in the main Gmail web interface. Advanced IMAP controls were recently rolled out to all users, so certain labels/folders may have been deemed hidden.

Click SETTINGS and then within the LABELS section, check mark those boxes whose labels you want shown as IMAP folders by selecting SHOW IN IMAP.

===========

UPDATE: Also check within K9 ACCOUNT SETTINGS > FOLDERS and make sure certain folders aren't hidden.

Comment: Yeah, checked that.  All my folders except "Chat" are enabled.  Tried unchecking them, then re-enabling to no luck.

Comment: In that case, try wiping everything from K9 and setting up your account again.

Comment: That finally did it, thanks!  Something must of gone wonky the first setup.

Comment: What in particular worked? Clean re-install or folder settings?

Comment: Changing the folder settings didn't work.  So from the accounts page, I brought up the Accounts Options page, then clicked on Remove Account.  I re-readded the account this time, and made sure all the settings where correct.  My hunch is last time I used the automatic setup for my gmail account and this is where things went wrong

Answer (score 4):

I went to the folder list. I then hit my menu button & a new menu popped up that said "refresh folders" on the bottom.  When I did that, it grabbed the new folders I created & removed the ones I had deleted (from using previous webmail programs).

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem (with a non-gmail IMAP account), what worked for me was to monkey with it. Set all the folder settings to display only subscribed folders. Then refresh folders. Then change it to display all folders. Now I can see my newer IMAP folders.

So ... if you're loathe to re-install your account, try just changing the folder display settings around and then changing them back.